# Accurate geometry in Java

Tags: java, geometry, computational-geometry

I'm coding an application in Java that requires quite a lot of geometry. I made heavy use of existing classes and my calculations so far have been in double precision (so I'm using for instance, Point2D.Double, Line2D.Double and coded a convex polygon class using the latter...).

I ran into several issues relating to double precision calculations that make my application at times unstable and I considered switching to BigDecimal but that would imply creating creating my own Point2D, Line2D classes with BigDecimals etc, and rewriting several functions. Another solution would be to accept the imprecisions and deal with them; i.e. A point is actually a small square, a line is a an infinite band, a point lies on a line if the square and the band intersect and so on. Although this solution can be implemented quickly my code would be disfigured by statements like (Math.abs(x) < precision) (to signify that x == 0) scattered here and there.

Is someone aware of nice clean way to do accurate geometry in Java?

Answer (score 1):

<sub>I tried to squeeze (parts of) this into a comment, but it didn't fit. You should *not* consider this as "THE" answer, but there are some points that I would like to list here.</sub>

The recommendation to use `BigDecimal` is annoyingly common whenever someone mentions precision problems with `float` or `double` - and yet is equally inappropriate in such cases as this one. In all but the fewest cases, the limited precision of `double` is simply not relevant.

<sup>Unless, maybe, you are writing software that should compute the trajectory of a manned spacecraft that is about to be sent to Mars, or doing other highly scientific computations.</sup>

Additionally, replacing `double` with `BigDecimal` tends to only replace one small problem with several larger ones. For example, you'll have to think about the `RoundingMode` and "scale", which can be tricky. And eventually, you will notice that a simple value like `1.0/3.0` can't be represented with `BigDecimal` either.

For your particular application case, there are more caveats:

Even with a `BigDecimal`-based implementation of `Point2D`, the data would still be exposed as `double`, via the `getX()`/`getY()` methods. For example, a method like [Line2D#ptLineDistSq](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Line2D.html#ptLineDistSq-java.awt.geom.Point2D-) will still use the `double` values. This could only be avoided if you wrote *everything* that is related to your computations, from scratch, using `BigDecimal` really *everywhere*.

But even if you did this: You cannot compute the slope of a line from the point (-1,0) to the point (2,1), and you cannot say where this line intersects the y-axis. You might try some rational number representation here, but there's still this issue with the length of the diagonal of a unit square - which is an irrational number.

The imprecisions of `double` are annoying. You can compute whether a point is *left* of a line or *right* of a line. And due to the precision issues, it may well be that it is *both*. Doing computations with points that should "mathematically" be *equal*, but differ by some small floating-point error can lead to bogus results (I also stumbled over this in [one of my libraries](https://github.com/javagl/Geom)).

As you already mentioned in the question: Some concepts that work in pure mathematics have to be rethought when they should be implemented with limited precision. Any `==` comparison is a no-go, and other comparisons should be carefully validated, taking the possible rounding errors into account.

But using some "epsilon"-based comparisons is the usual way to deal with this. Of course, they make the code a bit more clumsy. But compare this to some "arbitrary precision" code with `BigDecimal`:

```
BigDecimal computeArea(BigDecimal radius) {
    // Let's be very precise here....
    BigDecimal pi = new BigDecimal("3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117067982148086513282306647093844609550582231725359408128481117450284102701938521105559644622948954930381964428810975665933446128475648233786783165271201909145648566923460348610454326648213393607260249141273724587006606315588174881520920962829254091715364367892590360011330530548820466521384146951941511609433057270365759591953092186117381932611793105118548074462379962749567351885752724891227938183011949129833673362440656643086021394946395224737190702179860943702770539217176293176752384674818467669405132000568127145263560827785771342757789609173637178721468440901224953430146549585371050792279689258923542019956112129021960864034418159813629774771309960518707211349999998372978049951059731732816096318595024459455346908302642522308253344685035261931188171010003137838752886587533208381420617177669147303598253490428755468731159562863882353787593751957781857780532171226806613001927876611195909216420198938095257201065485863278865936153381827968230301952035301852968995773622599413891249721775283479131515574857242454150695950829533116861727855889075098381754637464939319");
    BigDecimal radiusSquared = radius.multiply(radius);
    BigDecimal area = radiusSquared.multiply(pi);
    return area;
}
```

Vs.

```
double computeArea(double radius) {
    return Math.PI * radius * radius;
}
```

Also, the epsilon-based comparisons are still error-prone and raise some questions. Most prominently: How large should this "epsilon" be? Where should the epsilon-based comparison take place? However, existing implementations, like the geometric algorithms in http://www.geometrictools.com/ might give some ideas of how this can be done (even though they are implemented in C++, and became a bit less readable in the latest versions). They are time-tested and already show how to cope with many of the precision-related problems.

Comment: Thanks much Marco! This is in fact the kind of answer I was looking for. I simply wanted to make sure that there are no native classes that are of common use for that purpose.